# Creating a Coded UI map manually without recorder

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to find a way to create an Object Repository without using the recording function.  What I would like to do is create individual "pages" for each window of my WPF app (page object pattern for those who are familiar with WebDriver).

I want to avoid all the extra stuff coded UI records and adds to the project.  All I would like is a simple class that maps to all of the controls I want, and then use that class in my tests.

Is that possible with Coded UI, if so , how?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: err, you sure you want to do this in C?

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to be c#, thanks for the catch.

Comment: thought so, but you can never tell on here, people do the craziest things...

Answer (score 3):

There is a framework (set of helper classes) in codeplex that does exactly what you want but for websites. Since it is open source I imagine that it would not be too hard to adapt it for a WPF application. You can find all the details at:

http://codeduicodefirst.codeplex.com/